# How can I connect to docker Postgres server from PGAdmin4

Tags: postgresql, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, pgadmin-4

I am new to Docker containers but not quite new to Postgres (I delved a bit in the past).

The thing is I am trying to connect to a Postgres server started from the following Docker container [dpage/pgadmin4](https://hub.docker.com/r/dpage/pgadmin4/)

The issue is that I cannot connect to the server using PGAdmin4.
I am getting the following error:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Address not available
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I have the following yaml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: parola
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      
  pgadmin4:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: user@domain.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: parola
```

Using the psql command line I can connect to it only if I set -h 0.0.0.0, as follows:

```
psql -h 0.0.0.0 -U postgres
```

Can someone tell me what I need to set up in the yaml file or how I can configure so it allow connection from localhost/127.0.0.1?

I am running on Ubuntu 20.04.2, AMD64 with Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

service `pgadmin4` is not being able reach service `db` because inside `pgadmin4` at port 5432 there wont be any service running

With this configuration, you are only mapping the db to host machine's 5432 port. That is why you were able to run `psql -h 0.0.0.0 -U postgres` in your machine (host machine)

[According to docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) `pgadmin4` can access DB using host name `db`

you can link the configuration with some additional configuration as below

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: parola
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata

  pgadmin4:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: user@domain.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: parola
    volumes:
    - ./servers.json:/pgadmin4/servers.json
```

[add a file called `servers.json`](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/container_deployment.html#examples) in the same directory as docker-compose with the below c[ontents](https://github.com/postgres/pgadmin4/blob/master/web/pgadmin/setup/tests/servers.json). take note that I have added the Host as `db`

```
{
  "Servers": {
    "1": {
      "Name": "local db",
      "Group": "Server Group 1",
      "Port": 5432,
      "Username": "postgres",
      "Host": "db",
      "SSLMode": "prefer",
      "MaintenanceDB": "postgres"
    }
  }
}
```